# React js Material UI Switch Component in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make the attendance system and I am using switch component from React material UI (ref: https://material-ui.com/api/switch/).

How can I loop switch component in the loop so that each switch button toggle acts like each table rows? Below is my code block. Any Help? Currently when I toggle one switch then all the switch inside the loops are auto toggled.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        checkedB: false,
    }
    this.handleClassChange = this.handleClassChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.checked });
};

 {

  this.state.students.map((post, i) => (
  <TableRow key={i} className="tblFont">
  <TableCell scope="row">
  {post.ROLLNO}
  </TableCell>
  <TableCell>
  {post.STNAME}
  </TableCell>
  <TableCell>
      <Switch key={this.state[i]}
         checked={this.state.i}
         onChange={this.handleChange('checkedB')}
         value="checkedB"
         color="primary"
      />
  </TableCell>
</TableRow>
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the array and create state for each Switch. for example `{ switch-0: false, switch-1: false, ...}`

```
setDynamicSwitchState = (list) => {

  if (!list) {
    return
  }

  const switchState = {};

  list.forEach((item, index) => {
    switchState['switch-' + index] = false;
  });

  this.setState({
    switchState: switchState
  })
}
```

In your `handleChange`

```
handleChange = (index, event, checked) => {

  const list = Object.assign({}, this.state.switchState);

  list['switch-' + index] = checked;

  this.setState({
    switchState: list
  })
}
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7qowzb)

Comment: Thank you. But this logic is throwing the error when there is more number of student like 100s. Error : Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. Any idea how to solve this.

Comment: are you doing this `onChange={this.handleChange('checkedB')}`? cause that error is thrown when you call a function in render

Comment: Thank you so much, Junius. I forgot to change the switch component event, now I changed the switch component events and it worked fine.